# TopLayoutGuide offset within UIView drawing

Tags: uiview, mkmapview, autolayout

I have a custom view class derived from MKMapView which is overlapped at the top from an UINavigationBar to get this translucent style. I found out i must implement inside the UIViewController the TopLayoutGuide to move the top compass subview from the MKMapView in its right position to be visible. This works perfect, but i also have a custom subview inside my view and i cant figure out how i get the new top offset from the UIViewController from inside the View to position my subview correctly. How did Apple this magic for their subviews inside MKMapView?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to get the top layout guide position within an UIView to reposition subviews correctly

```
- (void)layoutSubviews
{
UIViewController *myController = (UIViewController*)[self nextResponder];
CGFloat top = myController.topLayoutGuide.length;

// reposition subviews
// ...
}
```